# How should I grant a user the privilege to restart the nagios services?

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo, nagios, redhat-satellite

What is the best way to grant user an access so they can restart the nagios services?

I have added in visudo

```
USER ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ServiceName *
```

But that did not work, I am using Red hat 6,

```
User name is ahmed
Service name : nagios
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux.  Sorry for the edited title but there are multiple ways of doing things and I'll be giving you one.  Whichever is "the best" is opinion-based, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: In what way did it "not work"?

Comment: Thanks Fabby, I am sorry if this is off topic, I am kinda new here so I was trying to get help from the Galaxy people.

Comment: and did you type in the literal line `USER ALL`..., or did you use `ahmed ALL`...?

Comment: I never messed with visudo file, Thanks Jeff I was using USER ALL not Ahmed ALL @JeffSchaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Nagios Documentation](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/startstop.html), Nagios is still init-based, so to allow any user to start and stop the Nagios service, we're going to:

- create an operator Command alias
- create an operator group
- allow anyone in the operator group to start/stop the Nagios Service:
- As an example, add the user "ahmed" to the operator group (as per your question)

first change the sudoers file:

```
sudo visudo
```

in the section `# Cmnd alias specification` add:

```
Cmnd_Alias      CMD_OPERATOR=/etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios
```

in the `### User privilege specification section ###` add:

```
# Allow the group "operator" to use certain applications
%operator       ALL=CMD_OPERATOR
```

Now create the group `operator`:

```
sudo groupadd operator
```

and add ahmed to the operator group:

```
sudo usermod --append --groups operator ahmed
```

That's it!  Now ahmed can perform all these commands:

```
sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios start
sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios reload
sudo /etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios stop
```

by providing his own password.

#### Why?

Well, now you have an operator group, you can:

- easily add other programs these kind of users need to perform
- easily revoke their operator rights if needed